# SLSQP failed to install in OpenMDAO

Tags: openmdao

I am trying to install OpenMDAO 0.10.3.2, but keep having trouble getting SLSQP to install. I followed the directions on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sMeDsoHdYw&noredirect=1), but for some reason this package is not coming through.

I believe the problem lies with my organization's firewall. To get around this, my advisor gave me the file and an additional line of code to separately install this package. This code is here:

```
go-openmdao.py --extra-search-dir=<dir>
```

Unfortunately it still is not working. Does anyone have any advice?

Thank you,

CBroslawski

Answer (score 0):

This is an old version of OpenMDAO that is no longer supported.  If extra-search-dir isn't working, you might want to try manually downloading SLSQP to your directory, activating the environment, and then trying to pip install SLSQP directly from its file.  `pip install /path/to/filename`

Comment: I ended up using the steps outlined in this thread I found (http://openmdao.org/forum/questions/852/install-issues-version-070). I basically ran the code they advised to install the slsqp package, then ran the base "python go-openmdao-0.10.3.2.py" to get everything else. This seemed to work, and using the same steps my coworker successfully passed the subsequent test, but when I ran the test I got 6 errors, for things like the test_access_controller, test_decorator, test_list, test_docs, and two others. I am not sure how to rectify these new errors! Thank you for your help!

Comment: If it helps, at least these four errors seem to all fall under "Error 3: The system cannot find the path specified 'U:\\\\.openmdao'